# How do I simplify the X-axis scale (year Quarters R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, r-markdown

3rd year uni student here, I have an econometry project to hand back on the 15th; we have to work with Rmd but I'm not really familiar with the tool... so any help would be much appreciated!
My problem here is that I want to display on a ggplot the evolution of GDP in Belgium throughout the years. Here's what my data looks like (you can see the Time column is organized with quarters [![Data to work with][1]][1]. I coded this:

```
ggplot(data = PIB, aes(x=PIB$Time, y=PIB$Belgium, group=1))  + geom_line() + labs(x="Time", y="Belgian PIB")
```

and here's the ouput I have:

[![ggplot evolution graph][2]][2]

I'm very satisfied with how the graph looks except for the X-axis. I looked online on many platforms but I can't for the life of me figure out how to organize the Time axis. The format of the column really throws me off.. I'd like for online 4/5 timestamps to be shown, so the reader can understand that the evolution goes from 2001 to 2021 and that the GDP changes every quarter.

I'm aware this is probably a stupid question but any help would be welcome!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvYNW.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1f1Ll.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert the time column from a character vector to time.

```
library(zoo)
PIB$Time = as.yearqtr(PIB$Time,format="%YQ%q")
PIB$Time = as.Date(PIB$Time)
```

Then try ggplot.

Comment: thank you so much! I knew the answer wasn't that complicated, I tried a lot of stuff that looked like what you did but I'm really not familiar with R, and I feel like it's much less intuitive than other programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

Convert Time to yearqtr class and use with `scale_x_yearqtr`.  See `?scale_x_yearqtr` to review its various arguments if the default is not what you want.

Note the information at the top of the [r](/questions/tagged/r) tag page and in particular R questions to SO should provide the input as text so that others can copy and paste it into their session. Images can't easily be used without retyping it all. In the absence of that I have used the reproducible input shown in the Note at the end.  Use any of these:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)

# 1
qplot(as.yearqtr(Time), Belgium, data = PIB, geom = "line", xlab = "") +
  scale_x_yearqtr()

# 2 - will default to scale_x_yearqtr even if not specified
qplot(as.yearqtr(Time), Belgium, data = PIB, geom = "line", xlab = "")

# 3 - convert to zoo series and plot that
Belgium <- read.zoo(PIB, FUN = as.yearqtr)
autoplot(Belgium) + xlab("")
```

[image: screenshot]

### Note

```
PIB <-
structure(list(Time = c("2001Q1", "2001Q2", "2001Q3", "2001Q4", 
"2002Q1", "2002Q2", "2002Q3", "2002Q4"), Belgium = 1:8), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```